# Sorting factors in multipanel plot in ggplot2 according to the first panel

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, facet

Is it possible to sort factors in a multipanel plot in `ggplot2` according to the first panel? The first panel decides the order and the remaining panels follow that order.

Here is an example:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(36)
xx<-data.frame(YEAR=rep(c("X","Y"), each=20),
               CLONE=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each=4, 2),
               TREAT=rep(c("T1","T2","T3","C"), 10),
               VALUE=sample(c(1:10), 40, replace=T))

ggplot(xx, aes(x=CLONE, y=VALUE, fill=YEAR)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~TREAT)
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image]

Now I would like to sort `CLONE` based on the `VALUE` in `YEAR X` in a descending order (highest to lowest) but only for the Control (`C` panel). This order should then be maintained for `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`. By looking at the plot above, I want panel `C` sorted as `CLONE C`, `B` or `D` (both are 5), `A` and `E`. This order of `CLONE` should then be replicated for the remaining panels.

Comment: You should/could define the clone variable as an ordered factor, in which you define the order based on the sorting within C. If i'm correct ggplot will maintain this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this right in ggplot since you have to reorder CLONE by
3 conditions, TREAT, YEAR and VALUE, otherwise `forcats::fct_reorder2` could have been an option.
Instead, extract the order of CLONE from the subset of data corresponding to YEAR = "X",
TREAT = "C", and re-define your factor levels for the whole data set based on this subset.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
set.seed(36)

xx <- data.frame(YEAR = rep(c("X","Y"), each = 20),
           CLONE = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each = 4, 2),
           TREAT = rep(c("T1","T2","T3","C"), 10),
           VALUE = sample(c(1:10), 40, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

clone_order <- xx %>% subset(TREAT == "C"  & YEAR == "X") %>%
  arrange(-VALUE) %>% select(CLONE) %>% unlist()

xx <- xx %>% mutate(CLONE = factor(CLONE, levels = clone_order))

ggplot(xx, aes(x = CLONE, y = VALUE, fill = YEAR)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~TREAT)
```

giving

[image: Barchart of CLONE ordered by a subpanel]