# Highlighting individual axis labels in bold using ggplot2

Tags: r, indexing, ggplot2

I want to highlight individual axis labels in bold. I am aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30036353/4308815) by @MrFlick but I can't figure out how to do this **a)** for more than one item, and **b)** whether it's possible to use the **names of the labels** instead of the number of the item in that list (or expression).

**Edit (start)**

I am also aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862452/4308815) but it colors the labels based on a fill aesthetics (i.e. `a <- ifelse(data$category == 0, "red", "blue"`)). This doesn't work for my case, as I *don't want to color the labels based on a fill aesthetics* but instead I want to make them **bold** individually the way I prefer.

**Edit (end)**

Here is an example dataset:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
set.seed(36)
xx<-data.frame(YEAR=rep(c("X","Y"), each=20),
               CLONE=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each=4, 2),
               TREAT=rep(c("T1","T2","T3","C"), 10),
               VALUE=sample(c(1:10), 40, replace=T))
```

Then I am sorting my labels according to a particular factor combination which is then supposed to be maintained across multiple panels of a plot. See my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39668404/4308815).

```
clone_order <- xx %>% subset(TREAT == "C"  & YEAR == "X") %>%
  arrange(-VALUE) %>% select(CLONE) %>% unlist()    
xx <- xx %>% mutate(CLONE = factor(CLONE, levels = clone_order))

ggplot(xx, aes(x=CLONE, y=VALUE, fill=YEAR)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~TREAT)
```

[image]

Now I want to bold `Clone` `A`, `B` and `E`. I am sure this will work somehow but I cannot figure out how. Ideally, it would be great to know how to do this by **a)** using the number of the item in the list/expression, and **b)** by using the label, e.g. `A`, `B` and `E`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a generic method to create the emboldening vector:

```
colorado <- function(src, boulder) {
  if (!is.factor(src)) src <- factor(src)                   # make sure it's a factor
  src_levels <- levels(src)                                 # retrieve the levels in their order
  brave <- boulder %in% src_levels                          # make sure everything we want to make bold is actually in the factor levels
  if (all(brave)) {                                         # if so
    b_pos <- purrr::map_int(boulder, ~which(.==src_levels)) # then find out where they are
    b_vec <- rep("plain", length(src_levels))               # make'm all plain first
    b_vec[b_pos] <- "bold"                                  # make our targets bold
    b_vec                                                   # return the new vector
  } else {
    stop("All elements of 'boulder' must be in src")
  }
}

ggplot(xx, aes(x=CLONE, y=VALUE, fill=YEAR)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~TREAT) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(face=colorado(xx$CLONE, c("A", "B", "E"))))
```

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks! One more question, would it also be possible, besides making it bold, to increase the font size of the bold label by say 2pt using `size=` in `axis.text.x`?

Comment: Aye. Most of the `element_text()` params are vectorized, but you'd need to copy and adapt this function to be a `size` changer vs a `face` changer.

Comment: Trying to adapt this to alternatively top or bottom justify selected labels. I wrote code but it just produces a blank plot. Replaced "plain" with 1.0, and "bold" with 0.0 in your `colorado' function. And in plot call: `theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=colorado2(xx$CLONE, c("A", "B", "E"))))'. However changes take up half of plot which I don't want. Any ideas how to scale the 0 or 1 within the label area of the plot @hrbrmstr ?

Comment: def a new question anony-user @user2498193

Comment: ok no problem @hrbrmstr - new question is up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286116/justify-individual-axis-labels-in-bold-using-ggplot2 Appreciate your help if you have time !

Answer (score 19):

You can create a named vector of expressions (that turn text to bold) in `scale_x_discrete` and use `parse=TRUE` to evaluate the expressions:

```
ggplot(xx, aes(x=CLONE, y=VALUE, fill=YEAR)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    facet_wrap(~TREAT) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c("A"=expression(bold(A)), "C"=expression(bold(C)),
                              "E"=expression(bold(E)), parse=TRUE))
```

You can probably create the vector of expressions programmatically, rather than typing it out, but the way to do that is escaping me right now.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eipi10! I like this one too as it is simple (i.e. upvote). However the answer by @hrbrmstr provides me with more control.

Comment: Yes, I like his answer too.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure if you can map label characteristics by name, but it's definitely possible to do it by position with a call to `theme`:

```
ggplot(xx, aes(x=CLONE, y=VALUE, fill=YEAR)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~TREAT) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = c('bold', 'bold', 'plain', 'plain', 'bold')))
```

Note that the listed font faces for `axis.text.x` are the same length as the labels of your x-axis (five elements). This produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Using `axis.text.x` is definitely an option but a bit cumbersome since I have 34 factor levels. That's why I was hoping to somehow just specify the ones I want to be bold by name and not by counting the position. I upvoted your answer but would like to keep it open a little longer. Maybe someone has a different idea.

Comment: Playing with this a little more, it looks like `element_text` works only by position and ignores naming. One option for reducing typing would be judicious use of `rep`, for instance: `c(rep('plain', 10), rep(c('bold', 'plain', each = 2))` would make the first 10 labels plain, the next 2 bold, and the next 2 plain.

Comment: Exactly what I needed—thanks @jdobres! I used a logical vector to then create my  "face" vector.