# Format specific axis labels in ggplot2 without underlying data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make axis labels bold if they contain specific text. I'm trying to do this to a plot that's the output of a function that also manipulates the my data, so there's no longer a direct relationship between my input data and the order of the labels in the output. So adding `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = ifelse(levels(df$category) == "xxx", "bold", "plain")))` doesn't work (it turns the wrong label bold).

As a concrete example, if I had just [this box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVKtF.png) of petal length by iris species as an object, would it be possible add a layer that would turn "setosa" bold if I didn't know the order the species would appear in?

Update: a reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

test <- tribble(
    ~AreaName, ~Value,
    "London",   1,
    "New York", 5,
    "Paris",    3
)

compare_areas <- function(data, area, value) {

    area <- enquo(area)
    value <- enquo(value)

    newLevels <- data[order(data[[quo_text(value)]], decreasing = TRUE), ][[quo_text(area)]]

    print(newLevels)


    data[[quo_text(area)]] <- factor(data[[quo_text(area)]], levels = newLevels)
    print(data)
    p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x = quo_text(area), 
                                             y = quo_text(value))) +
        coord_flip() +
        geom_col()

    return(p)
}


compare_areas(data = test,
              area = AreaName,
              value = Value)
```

[Plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuTcF.png). So I'd want to make Paris bold, for example, but I don't know how the levels will be ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess and assume that all you have available is the `ggplot` object itself, i.e. after doing this:

```
library(ggplot2)
g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Petal.Length)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

you only have `g1`.  Since the data that are going to be used to render the plot are stored within `g1`, you can build on @Oliver's answer as follows:

```
g1 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = 
    ifelse(levels(g1$data$Species) == "setosa", "bold", "plain")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **`levels()`**. When you apply `df$category == "xxx"` you get as many `bold`, `plain` values as there are rows in `df`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Petal.Length)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = 
        ifelse(levels(iris$Species) == "setosa", "bold", "plain")))
```

[image]

The same is with `iris` dataset:

```
length(ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", "bold", "plain"))
[1] 150
length(ifelse(levels(iris$Species) == "setosa", "bold", "plain"))
[1] 3
```

Comment: Yes sorry that was a mistake on my part, but using `levels()` still doesn't work because the function that returns the plot also reorders the levels. 
Perhaps the ideal situation would be that the function would be split into a data cleaning function and a plotting function, but there's not much I can do about that right now

Comment: @Oliver then you should update your question with reproducible example: add function and data

Comment: This solution did not work for me either. The wrong level was made bold. But I found a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694490/highlighting-individual-axis-labels-in-bold-using-ggplot2