# bold an item in axis label after using reorder_within

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidytext

I am using the reorder_within() function from the tidytext package in R to make a plot of different frequencies. An analogous example comes from [here](https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/).

```
library(tidytext)

top_names %>%
    group_by(decade) %>%
    top_n(15) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
           name = reorder_within(name, n, decade)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = decade)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
    facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_x_reordered() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    labs(y = "Number of babies per decade",
         x = NULL,
         title = "What were the most common baby names in each decade?",
         subtitle = "Via US Social Security Administration")
```

The output image is:
[image]

How would I go about bolding an individual item in each facet? For example, if I wanted to bold the name David on each of the facets' axis labels, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can try one of the solutions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694490/highlighting-individual-axis-labels-in-bold-using-ggplot2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In contrast to the solutions in the answer linked by @tamtam, here is a solution that requires minimal overhead: You can use `ggtext::element_markdown` to interpret any text in the ggplot as markdown. Just add `axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown()` and all variable names that have the form `"**Name**"` are shown in bold:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

test_data <- data.frame(
  decade = rep(c("1950", "1960", "1970", "1980"), each = 3),
  name = rep(c("Max", "**David**", "Susan"), 4),
  n = c(2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 5, 7, 10, 4, 5, 3)
)


test_data %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, n, decade)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = decade)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(y = "Number of babies per decade",
       x = NULL,
       title = "What were the most common baby names in each decade?",
       subtitle = "Via US Social Security Administration") +
  theme(axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great example of @starja you can try using `glue` package to build a condition over the name and then use the functions for ordering. The key is to format the labels as `element_markdown()` from `ggtext`. Here the code using the entire data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)
library(babynames)
#Data
top_names <- babynames %>%
  filter(year >= 1950,
         year < 1990) %>%
  mutate(decade = (year %/% 10) * 10) %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  count(name, wt = n, sort = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup
#Plot
top_names %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  top_n(15) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(name=ifelse(name=='David',glue("**{name}**"),name)) %>%
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, n, decade)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = decade)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(y = "Number of babies per decade",
       x = NULL,
       title = "What were the most common baby names in each decade?",
       subtitle = "Via US Social Security Administration")+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

Output:

[image]